# How can I trim the end of a money data type in sql

Tags: sql

Say I have a column that is a money data type in a table, $53125, and I want to update the table's 'sales' column, so that it would instead be $53 for this cell (as an example). Is this possible?

Comment: `UPDATE tab_name SET sales = FLOOR(sales/1000) WHERE ...`

Comment: You can divide by thousand and then ROUND to zero digits.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL (the query language) does not have a "money" data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql, the syntax looks like this

```
UPDATE orders 
SET sales = CONCAT("$", FLOOR(sales/1000))
```

Decimal data types, only serve floating point numbers. To convert to currency, you would have to use the `CONCAT` method.

To round down to the nearest 1,000, you use the `floor` method.